# Get the information of a row when a check is checked

Tags: jquery, python, django

I need to get the information of a checked row.

[image: Table]

I need to get the value of the colum precio but only if the checkbox is checked. I need the price to make a sum after I get it.

I get the information for the table using python and django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to check for row values, without ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name='check[]']").click(function(){
var values = "";
   $.each($("input[name='check[]']:checked"), function(index,value) {
       var data = $(this).parents('tr:eq(0)');
       if(index > 0)
           values += " and ";

       values += $(data).find('td:eq(1)').text() ;
   });

   alert(values);
 });
});
```

Working fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/SQjEC/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here

1. load all of the values in hidden fields, and use javascript to make them only appear once the checkbox is checked, and disappear if it is unchecked.
2. The better option is to use ajax, check this: https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/2008/11/24/a-simple-django-example-with-ajax/

In both cases, you'd need a listener on these checkboxes, so your javascript code could look something like this:

```
function checkboxHandler(){    
   if(this.checked){
      //do something
   }
   else{
      //do something else
   }
}
```